# Is there any way to prioritize a rule by its own slot in CLIPS?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, rules, clips, slot, expert-system

Is there anyway to make a rule fire earlier given a specific slot value that a fact may have?
I was wondering if there is anything like dynamic salience but for slot values
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It's likely there's a more elegant solution to whatever problem you're solving than changing the salience of a rule based on a slot value, but since you can use a global variable for the salience value of a rule, you can dynamically change the salience for a rule by assigning the global a value pulled from a fact slot:

```
         CLIPS (6.31 6/12/19)
CLIPS> (set-salience-evaluation every-cycle)
when-defined
CLIPS> 
(defglobal ?*r-1* = 0
           ?*r-2* = 0)
CLIPS>            
(deftemplate rule-priority
   (slot rule)
   (slot salience))
CLIPS>    
(deffacts start
   (rule-priority (rule r-1) (salience -10))
   (rule-priority (rule r-2) (salience -10))
   (prime))
CLIPS>    
(defrule assign
   (declare (salience 10000))
   (rule-priority (rule ?r) (salience ?s))
   =>
   (eval (str-cat "(bind ?*" ?r "* " ?s ")")))
CLIPS>   
(defrule start
   ?rp <- (rule-priority (rule r-2) (salience ~10))
   =>
   (modify ?rp (salience 10)))
CLIPS>           
(defrule r-1
   (declare (salience ?*r-1*))
   (prime)
   =>)
CLIPS>    
(defrule r-2
   (declare (salience ?*r-2*))
   (prime)
   =>)
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (agenda)
10000  assign: f-2
10000  assign: f-1
0      r-1: f-3
0      r-2: f-3
0      start: f-2
For a total of 5 activations.
CLIPS> (run 2)
CLIPS> (agenda)
0      start: f-2
-10    r-1: f-3
-10    r-2: f-3
For a total of 3 activations.
CLIPS> (run 1)
CLIPS> (agenda)
10000  assign: f-4
-10    r-1: f-3
-10    r-2: f-3
For a total of 3 activations.
CLIPS> (run 1)
CLIPS> (agenda)
10     r-2: f-3
-10    r-1: f-3
For a total of 2 activations.
CLIPS>
```

You can also dynamically assign the salience of a rule using a deffuction and retrieve the slot value using the fact query functions:

```
CLIPS> (clear)
CLIPS> (set-salience-evaluation every-cycle)
every-cycle
CLIPS> 
(deftemplate rule-priority
   (slot rule)
   (slot salience))
CLIPS>    
(deffunction get-salience (?rule)
   (do-for-fact ((?rp rule-priority)) 
                (eq ?rp:rule ?rule)
      (return ?rp:salience))
   (return 0))
CLIPS>    
(deffacts priorities
   (rule-priority (rule r-1) (salience -10))
   (rule-priority (rule r-2) (salience -10))
   (prime))
CLIPS>    
(defrule start
   ?rp <- (rule-priority (rule r-2) (salience ~10))
   =>
   (modify ?rp (salience 10)))
CLIPS>       
(defrule r-1
   (declare (salience (get-salience r-1)))
   (prime)
   =>)
CLIPS>    
(defrule r-2
   (declare (salience (get-salience r-2)))
   (prime)
   =>)
CLIPS> (reset)
CLIPS> (agenda)
0      start: f-2
-10    r-1: f-3
-10    r-2: f-3
For a total of 3 activations.
CLIPS> (run 1)
CLIPS> (agenda)
10     r-2: f-3
-10    r-1: f-3
For a total of 2 activations.
CLIPS>
```